# servelt request parameter value contains ampersand?

Tags: java, url, urlencode, url-parameters

I have below the url.

```
http://localhost:8080/servlet?user=John&message=hai&hello&recipient=scott
```

In above url i have 3 request parameters as below.

```
user=John
message=hai&hello
recipient=scott
```

Here the problem is with `message` request parameter's value.because here its value contains ampersend (&). when i try `request.getParameter("message")` then i get only `hai` but not `hai&hello`. How can i solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, instead `....&message=hi%26hello....`. I mean, encode it.

**[Edited]**

As you said you have no control over it, and it is legacy application and they cannot fix it; then you can still, I suppose, use `URLEncoder` to encode the URL.

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
// Then use encodedUrl as you were using url.
```

**[Edited]**

..or just treat it as a `String`. Simple, isn't it?

```
// Please refactor.
String[] paramPart = url.split("?");
String[] params = paramPart[1].split("&");
Map<String, String> paraMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
  String[] keyValue;
  if(params[i].contains("=")) {
    keyValue = params[i].split("=");
    paraMap.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
  } else {
    params[i-1] = params[i-1] + "&" + params[i];
    keyValue = params[i-1].split("=");
    paraMap.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ansari, Thanks for your reply. i dont have control over the url.it is sent by some external client...

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `&recipient` always comes after `&message` or that `&message` may come as last parameter or you know the set of possible parameters, then you will need the get the query string from the request and try to split it accordingly.

For example if `&recipient` alway comes after `&message` then you could do (pseudo code / untested):

```
int s = queryString.indexOf("&message");
int e = queryString.indexOf("&recipient");
String messageValue = queryString.substring(s + "&message".length(), e);
```