# & converted to &amp; sometimes on request.getParameter("url") in jsp servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have very simple input on HTML on JSP:

```
<input type="text" name="url" value="" />
```

User enters following value in above input:

```
http://www.example.com/param1=a&param2=b
```

On servlet side, when I do `request.getParameter("url")` I am getting following :

```
http://www.example.com/param1=a&amp;param2=b
```

How can I get original URL without `&amp;` from `request.getParameter`?

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18779689/517134 it may help you

Comment: Hi have control over the client code though and can change it, is there no other way except URL encoding ? It still fails with that

Comment: How do you know that yo're getting that? Where do you see this value? Your question talks about an HTML form, then about client code. How is this form really submitted?

Comment: Indeed, this is not the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
Just use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(url)` to escape any "&a m p;" (for that matter to escape any characters due to html encoding)